# Test filesystem stability / filesystem crash

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

Newbie here!!
Is there any way to crash filesystem or overload a filesystem so that it will get crash?
I want to check at what point my filesystem will get crash, and debug reason of crash.

Comment: What do you mean by `filesystem crash`? Your filesystem isn't a process, it can't crash. It might corrupt itself, or the driver chrashes which would crash your whole operating system.

Comment: @tkausl: The smart way to develop a filesystem driver would be in user mode, i.e. FUSE. That way, a driver crash doesn't crash Linux.

Comment: "overload a filesystem so that it will get crash" - that suggests an inevitability. Real filesystems do not crash, even under load. But it's still good to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a 1GB file.  Loop mount it as a block  device.  Format a filesystem on the loop device.  In the filesystem, create a 990MB file ...